# Restoring to a new phone without the restore password

Tags: iphone, backup, password, restore

I have a new phone and want to restore settings from the old one but can't remember my restore password. I can't seem to reset the password but can I reset iTunes somehow, do a new backup on the old phone then restore to the new one?

Comment: If you still have the old phone, change the backup password in iTunes and make a new backup, then restore that backup.